# MySQL is deprecrated

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems with MySQL in my PHP code

```
$konek= mysql_connect('localhost','root',' ');
if ($konek)
```

so, I cannot connect it to my DB and the mysql_connect is lined in the code like this picture.
[image]

> mysql_connect is deprecated

What's wrong with MySQL in my code? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: You should also note that this won't mix or interchange with other APIs, and that this library supports prepared statements, which should always be used for any variable input.